# Isn't there some way to have "just-for-fun" questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, scope

I can understand the need to keep things under control and nip problem trends in the bud based on the experience at SO and other graduated sites. While [tips] questions strain the discussion/list criteria, at least they're tidy if confined to one-per-language and all tagged.

But questions like ["Hello World in 1024 chars"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8859/hello-world-in-1024-characters) and "Creative Programming"; even though they attract riff-raff, they attract valuable contributors as well. Many of the 'historic' closed list questions on SO have massive votes and stars. But if we're too trigger happy, few participants can get into the *history books*.

Would it be possible to have a special [fun] tag, where say, you need a minimum rep to post (do some work first), and a restriction on frequency of usage (you've had your [fun] this month)?

And CW. (Have Cake+Eat Cake)

---

Comment: Am I to take it that this not exactly a request to change the FAQ but one for some kind of occasional relaxation of some of the rules?

Comment: I'm not sure what criteria we would use to decide *which* just for fun questions to let in, and without knowing that it's hard to say  where to go with this.
Suggestions are solicited for all comers.

Comment: Related: [Should we consider dropping or modifying the "objective winning criteria" requirement?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/564/78).

Comment: Exactly. I respect the difficulty you faced in having to be the "bad guy". And at the same time the rules are there for good reason. But *contradicta sunt complementa*; there's got to be a third way. And to relax a rule, often needs supplementary rules to shore-up the flank. I don't think my proposal is quite *there* yet... I'll investigate that link...

Comment: I recently had an issue with this, a question was declared off topic because there's no clear winner... https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160577/the-great-api-easter-egg-hunt/160851 I don't quite understand why a just-for-fun challenge isn't allowed.